# how to hook into open even in flexigrid

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

I am using flexigrid to pull data from a page

```
 $("#Details").flexigrid({
                        url: 'getdata.aspx?id=' + $("#txtSelectedID").val() + '&breakdown=true',
                        dataType: 'json', colModel: [
                                    { display: 'Description', name: 'BreakDetails', width: 300, align: 'left' },
                                    { display: 'Percentage', name: 'BreakVal1', width: 50, align: 'left' },
                                    { display: 'Amount', name: 'BreakVal2', width: 50, align: 'left' },
                                    { display: 'Total', name: 'BreakVal3', width: 50, align: 'left' }
                                    ],
                        preProcess: formatBreakdownResults,
                        width: 550, Height:550
                    });
```

Now I want to show it inside a dialog once it loads. is there an event like open or loaded?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, do you want to execute some code after the grid completely loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about extending one of these event?

```
preProcess: false,
onSuccess: false,  
onSubmit: false
```